# How remove empty values from the top of the Sort MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have these objects:

- A: Description: "A"
- B: Description: "B"
- C: Description: ""

When I use Mongodb sort for the field Description I get the following sort order:

- C: Description: ""
- A: Description: "A"
- B: Description: "B"

How I can move empty values to the bottom of the result?

My code is:

```
private void Sort(MongoCursor<Item> cursor, Sort sort)
{
    if (sort.Ascending)
    {
        cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending(sort.Field));
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending(sort.Field));
    }
}
```

Comment: you make them a value that is so high (in lexicographical order) no other value will get to it

Comment: or do it in the client after you've fetched them?

Comment: We have a pagination on client side. So we implement it. But it is pain in the neck.